# CakePHP3: how to get the count of associated

Tags: cakephp-3.x

I don't understand how to specify a query to get the count of associated.
In my example, Agthemes belongs to Agplans.
And in the DB, 4 Agthemes belong to Agplan id 22 and 1 Agthemes belongs to Agplan id 23.

I currently wrote the following query which returns a count of 5 in the Agthemes array of the 1st Agplans array and an empty Agthemes array for the second one.

```
$agplans = $this->Agplans->find()
   ->contain([
           'Agthemes' => function ($q) {
               return $q->select(
                   [
                       'id',
                       'agplan_id',
                       'count' => $q->func()->count('*')
                   ]);
           }
       ])
   ->where([
            'site_id' => $site->id
      ])
   ->all();
```

How to correctly write this query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have also to group the Agthemes

```
->contain([
    'Agthemes' => function ($q) {
        return $q->select(
            [
                'id',
                'agplan_id',
                'count' => $q->func()->count('*')
           ])
           ->group(['agplan_id']);
       }
   ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way for hasMany instances. Note the leftJoin instead of contains.

```
$userTableQuery = $UsersTable->find();
$data = $userTableQuery
    ->select([
        'Users.id',
        'order count' => $userTableQuery->func()->count('Orders.id')
    ])
    ->leftJoinWith('Orders')
    ->group('Users.id');
```